# Mixing fixed with and percentage width

Tags: html, css, positioning

I am trying to construct a layout in my "app-view" div where the "leftPane" has a fixed with and the "rightPane's" width extends with the browser width (percentage). Is this possible with CSS (no Javascript)? Below are my basic styles for the layout in the div.

```
#app-view
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}

#leftPane
{
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    max-width: 250px;
    height: 400px;
    background: blue;
}

#rightPane
{
    float: left;
    width: 66.66%;
    height: 400px;
    background: green;
}
```

Comment: I may have found a solution, but I am not sure if it is the most elegant. I am not floating the rightPane and am giving it a 100% width and a left margin of 250px. I am also removing the float on the header as it was causing issues. If anyone knows a more elegant solution, I would still like to hear it!

Comment: I think my solution should work best for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `left` and `right` on `#rightPane` instead of width. You also need to make `#app-view` positioned relatively and both panes absolute.

```
#app-view
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
}

#leftPane, #rightPane 
{
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

#leftPane
{
    width: 250px;
    background: blue;
}

#rightPane
{
    left: 250px;
    right: 0;
    background: green;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wRH9a/)**

Comment: Thanks! What if I wanted the app-view, left and right panes to be 100% of the height with a sticky footer?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
  <div id="leftpane" style="float: left; width: 250px;">left pane content</div>
  <div id="rightpane" style="margin-left: 250px;">right pane content</div>
</div>
```